# If jQuery form is valid show hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I've been messing with some form validation with two identical forms. So far I have the default HTML validation on the form, but for some reason when I submit the form, it reload the form it doesn't show my message that it's been successful.

Here's what I have for the form:

**HTML**

```
<div class="place-form">
   <div class="success-msg" style="display:none;">
    <p>Thanks for your submission! We will contact you shortly.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <form id="place-form-item">
    <div class="form-row">
      <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Your Last Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input id="form-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-row">
      <button class="submit-btn">submit</button>
    </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".submit-btn").click(function(e){
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.find("#place-form-item").valid()) {
       $this.parents(".form-wrap").hide();
       $this.parents().next(".success-msg").show()
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Not sure how to get it so that upon click, the form passed validation and then hides the one form and shows the success message. Unless I'm targeting something incorrectly.

Comment: check if `e.preventDefault();` isn't blocking the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you know that the `.valid()` method is a JQuery plug-in, right? Without the plug-in, the code in the `if` statement will never be reached.

There is a pure JavaScript API for checking a form's validity against the HTML5 validity framework - `.checkValidity()`.

Next, your `.next()` call isn't going to find the success message because it isn't the next element from your button.  Both that and your `.find()` calls can be replaced by using a higher level selector as context for a search.

Next, don't work with the submit button's `click` event. Work with the form's `submit` event.

Lastly, it's better to work with CSS classes than to dynamically create inline styles on an element.

```js
$("#place-form-item").on("submit", function(e){
   var $this = $(this);
   if(this.checkValidity()) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $this.parents(".form-wrap").hide();
      $(".success-msg", ".place-form").removeClass("hidden")
   }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="place-form">

  <div class="success-msg hidden">
    Thanks for your submission! We will contact you shortly.
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-wrap">
  
    <form id="place-form-item">
      <div class="form-row">
        <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Your Last Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <input id="form-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-row">
        <button class="submit-btn">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that's what I was wondering. I couldn't figure out why .valid() kept erring out in the console. But this is what I was looking for since I knew that there was (or is) a HTML5 solution for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Intercept the submit event, prevent the default form submission, and substitute your own action.

```
$("#my-form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** only targets the sibling that immediately **follows** the target. Given your structure, `.success-msg` **precedes** `.form-wrap`. As such, `.next()` cannot target it.

To resolve this, instead of `$this.parents().next(".success-msg").show()`, you can target the parent element `.place-form` and then make use of **[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** to find the relevant `.success-msg` with `$this.parents(".place-form").find(".success-msg").show()`.

You'll also want to move your `e.preventDefault()` to outside of your conditional.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
$(".submit-btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($('#place-form-item').valid()) {
    $this.parents(".form-wrap").hide();
    $this.parents(".place-form").find(".success-msg").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<div class="place-form">
  <div class="success-msg" style="display:none;">
    <p>Thanks for your submission! We will contact you shortly.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-wrap">
    <form id="place-form-item">
      <div class="form-row">
        <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <input id="lname" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Your Last Name" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <input id="form-email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />
      </div>
      <div class="btn-row">
        <button class="submit-btn">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)